# Tkinter Text: calling a custom function with the word selected by double-click

Tags: python, tkinter, callback, text-widget

When the user double click a word in a Text widget, some internal callback is called, which results in the selection of a word. I want to have some additionnal task to be done on that word. How can I do that? The naive idea was to bind my own callback to the double click. It did not worked, because of a wrong priority: my callback was executed first, before the word is selected, and the Text callback wascalled after.
How can I solve that?

An idea would be to retreive a handle to the existing callback and reuse it after:

```
actual_callback = **<how can I get this handle?>**    
text.bind("<Double-Button-1>", my_callback)
```

then my callback would straightforwardly write as follows:

```
def my_callback(event):
    actual_callback(event) # this will select the word
    w = text.selection_get()
    do_something(w)
```

Please help to finalize it this way, or feel free to propose a better way of acheiving my original goal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easy answer is to simply wait a beat before running your callback.

```
text.bind("<Double-Button-1>", lambda e: text.after(2, my_callback, e)) # wait 2 ms before running callback
```

Comment: Wow. I am impressed. I did not know this Text.after method. It worked at perfection. Thanks.

Comment: I think `text.after(0, my_callback, e)` would work just as well. It should be assigning the callback to the next event after the current click event is finished. I also think you may have a typo:  `wait a beat`

Comment: @quickbug the `after()` method is how you perform any timed actions in tkinter because `wait()` and `sleep()` will cause your entire program to freeze instead of just providing a timed event.

Comment: Thanks for the inlights. btw, I changed the title of the post to reflect the solution given by Novel. Hope it will help others with the same needs to be redirected to this post.

Comment: @quickbug all tkinter widgets have an `after` method.